# squared boxes by height (not width) to create equal width (aspect ratio)

Tags: css, height, css-grid, aspect-ratio

I know the squared solution with `:before { padding-bottom }`. This works only with a width value, because padding is always using a relation to the parents width. - But exactly this is my problem.

I ONLY have the value of the a fixed **HEIGHT** (by parent container) and I need squared boxes by that height value. I don't like to use JS. If there is a solution to **REPLACE** the **STATIC WIDTH** value with pure CSS, please tell me!

Here's a simple code sample:

```css
div.wrapper {
  height: 70px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: black;
}

div.box {
  float: left;
  width: calc(70px - 10px); /* here is that static value for width, but better would be a relation to (parent) height */
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
 }

div.box.b1 {
  background: orange;
}

div.box.b2 {
  background: red;
}

div.box.b3 {
  background: green;
}

div.box.b4 {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

div.box.b5 {
  float: right;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box b1">A</div>
  <div class="box b2">B</div>
  <div class="box b3">C</div>
  <div class="box b4">D</div>
  <div class="box b5">E</div>
</div>
```

I also was looking for the "css-3 grid", but I didn't found a good solution. But if anyone know about thet problem, please tell me! :)

PS: Just for info... The width of the parent is always 100% (or vw). I want to create a navbar with a defined height, which may be changed via media queries. But only the height value, never the width value of the parent container.

PPS: I found some more question here about that problem, but nobody understood the enquirers. Because we are not looking for "var height = width", we're looking for "var width = height". ;)

Comment: if you will defined the height of the parent then use CSS variable to reuse the same value in the height/width of childs

Comment: Yeah, but it's only bad for the IE compatibility.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiVo3.png) 
:/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a way with grid and css-vars...

```css
:root {
  --box-spacing: 10px;
  --box-length: 60px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, var(--box-length)) auto var(--box-length);
  grid-auto-rows: var(--box-length);
  grid-template-areas: 
    "a b c d . e";
  grid-gap: var(--box-spacing);
  padding: var(--box-spacing);
  background:black;
}

.grid > :nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: a;
  background:orange;
}

.grid > :nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: b;
  background:red;
}

.grid > :nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: c;
  background:green;
}

.grid > :nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: d;
  background:blue;
}

.grid > :nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: e;
  background:grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
</div>
```

I simply use the same var() for width and width lengths. And `grid-template-areas` allows it to use `.` for an empty column at the fifth position. That column has an auto width.

It's not beauty, but it works... if you've a better solution, tell me! :)