# Flex row force child image to shrink height to 100% of other content

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Take the following example;

```css
.row {
  background: #F88;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.cont {
  display: block;
  height: 82px;
  width: 82px;
  background-color: #0AF;
}

.txt {
  background-color: #0C0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-auto"><div class="cont">82px</div></div>
    <div class="col-auto"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/WIxmfZb.png" /></div>
    <div class="col"><div class="txt">Text content</div></div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I would like the 100x100 image to shrink to the height of the next-tallest column (in the example this would be the 82px block element in the 1st column) while maintaining its aspect ratio.

So far I have attempted various different combinations of flex-basis, flex-shrink, and one solution which I managed to *kind of* get to work is to set the style of the image to `height: 0; min-height: 100%;` which works in the inspector, however;

- It exposed a bug in Chrome, where the width of the image is initially 0 until you resize the window, which will pop it into the correct aspect ratio
- It didn't work in IE >_>
- I'm pretty sure it violates some kind of international law against torturing the next dev that would have to pick my code up

After a couple of hours of brute-force I've yet to find a solution where

- The image correctly fills 100% of the flex height (ignoring its own height)
- The image maintains its aspect ratio
- The image doesn't overflow
- The image isn't absolutely positioned
- The size of the image isn't explicitly set

The ideal solution should look like this;

[image: Ideal solution]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: is the aspect ratio known?

Comment: @TemaniAfif In my particular circumstance the image is always 1:1

Comment: a similar issue asked today: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56326810/8620333 but in your case you don't even know the height. I think there is no direct or trivial way to achieve this

Comment: Made it in JS fiddle, but it doesn't quite follow your structure and the image is being displayed as a background image which might not be ideal in your situation, but it does exactly what you want it to visually. 

https://jsfiddle.net/xv43mfct/

Comment: An interesting solution to use grids, but unfortunately it's not ideal for my situation as both col 1 and 3 are variable height and I can't ensure col 1 is 1:1

Comment: well, it's very easily done with javascript, if that's an option.

Comment: It looks as though that might be my only option. Start off with the height of the image as zero, then set the height of the image to the height of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

I set the image to the same height as the first column by restricting its width to the same dimension:

```
.same-as-column-1 {
  max-width: 82px;
}
```

I wasn't sure if the third column was allowed to be taller, it locks up nicely if restricted to the same height as well but not sure that works for real use case.

Either way the image seems to meet the requirements, fills 100% of the flex height, maintains its aspect ratio, doesn't overflow, and isn't absolutely positioned/

```css
.row {
  background: #F88;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.cont {
  display: block;
  height: 82px;
  width: 82px;
  background-color: #0AF;
}

.same-as-column-1 {
  max-width: 82px;
}

.txt {
  background-color: #0C0;
  max-height: 82px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row no-gutters flex-row flex-nowrap">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <div class="cont">
        82px
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <img class="same-as-column-1" src="https://i.imgur.com/WIxmfZb.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="txt">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin sit amet massa quis nunc porta rutrum nec ac tellus. Phasellus eget ligula tristique, tristique elit ac, mollis eros. Aenean lobortis volutpat sem, et eleifend metus faucibus sed.
          Vivamus at varius nibh. Suspendisse rhoncus posuere elit sed tincidunt. Curabitur blandit in ipsum ut tempor. Mauris et eleifend justo. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris sollicitudin
          vehicula urna, egestas cursus dolor efficitur id. Aenean tempus vestibulum mauris, a accumsan sem vulputate quis. Maecenas tempor rhoncus molestie. Proin erat metus, cursus lacinia sodales non, malesuada non felis.</p>

        <p>Ut ac luctus elit. Mauris id ipsum id dolor hendrerit rhoncus. Fusce a ligula gravida, porttitor magna a, feugiat est. Maecenas at leo mi. Phasellus volutpat ex vitae nisl euismod, a luctus odio tristique. Maecenas eget tincidunt eros. Etiam auctor
          velit at felis condimentum, sit amet feugiat dolor auctor. Mauris tempus nulla quis ullamcorper porttitor. Etiam nec neque congue, molestie diam vel, suscipit dui. Sed mollis id dolor ut lacinia. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse ut pellentesque metus.
          In tincidunt ante at pretium mattis. Aliquam egestas neque vel nisi cursus rhoncus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whoops, forgot to include that I dont want the height of the image to be set explicitly. I have however, in my current situation, resorted to doing it.